# form.io Submit search value for Table Lookup Component in Javascript

Tags: javascript, submit, formio

I'm using a software that has a derived form.io form maker.
So probably I can't use al the features of a full form.io page

However I have a Date Field called MeetingDate and a Table Lookup Component called MeetingTable.
The MeetingTable has this script in Data > Calculated value:

`value=data.MeetingDate;`

The value is copied from MeetingDate to MeetingTable but the table does not return the rows for that date. I have to click on the triple-dot button to "refresh" the table or to "submit" the search value.
Is it possible to do this "submit" on the MeetingTable automatically on MeetingDate change?
Is it possible to do this with javascript?
Please be patient and "verbose" with your explanation because this is my very first project with form.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simpler than i think thought...no "Calculated value" needed!
Simply set the "lookup" flag in "Table Lookup Component > Data" for the colum you desire and bind it to the "Form component" Date Field called MeetingDate